# How to transmit a link to an object to anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, class, anonymous-function

I'm making a class that loads an image and calls its method after loading.

```
function Texture(){
    this.afterload = function(){
        document.write("loaded!");
    }
    this.load = function(name){
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = name;
        this.img.onload = function(){
            // there is the problem - how to pass "this" to anonymous function?
            this.afterload();
        }
    }
}

texture = new Texture();
texture.load("something.png")​;​
// now it should write "loaded" after loading the image.
```

but the problem is passing a link to the object. When I use this, it doesn't work.

So is there a way to pass object instance to an anonymous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to copy `this` to a lexical variable:

```
    this.load = function(name){
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = name;
        var _this = this;
        this.img.onload = function(){
            _this.afterload(); // use local variable, '_this', instead of 'this'
        };
    };
```

The anonymous function will "capture" or "close over" that variable, and will still be able to refer to it even after its containing function has returned.

Answer (score 1):

define another variable pointing to the object outside of your inner function and use this variable to reference it.

```
var that = this;
this.img.onload = function(){
    that.afterload();
};
```